# How to inherit Django variables?

Tags: python, html, django, inheritance

I'm having a little trouble wrapping my head around inheritance in Django. Here is an abstracted test case of my problem. (Note that my app is called `viz` and I've just built this test case under it)

## urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from viz import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('test.html', views.test_view, {}, name='test'),
    path('inherit_from_test.html', views.inherit_from_test_view, {}, name='inherit_test')
]
```

## viz/views.py

```
def test_view(request):
    return render(request, "viz/test.html", context={'hello': 'hello'})


def inherit_from_test_view(request):
    return render(request, "viz/inherit_from_test.html", context={'django': 'django' })
```

## viz/static/viz/test.html

```
<body>
<h1>
    {{ hello }}
</h1>
<h2>
    {% block content %}

    {% endblock %}
</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

## viz/static/viz/inherit_from_test.html

```
{% extends "viz/test.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {{ django }}
{% endblock %}
```

As expected, the `test.html` file has a single `h1` tag, which says `hello`. However I was expecting to see the both the `h1` and `h2` tag in `inherit_from_test.html`. Instead the `inherit_from_test.html` file only contains the `h2` tag saying `Django`.

Why has the `inherit_from_test.html` not inherited the contents of the `{{ hello }}` variable?

How can I make the contents of `{{ hello }}` available in the inherited template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates inherit; views do not. Only your `test_view` sends the `hello` variable to the context. It's not present when you call `inherit_from_test_view`.

Comment: So what would be the best way to ensure the `hello` variable is available in `inherit_from_test_view`? In my case the `hello` variable is a form that I want available in both template and inherited template.

Comment: The usual solutions involve [custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/) or [context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext)

Answer (score 1):

In Order for the heading to display (variable "hello" ) it needs to be present in your context.

Though you are inheriting the template, there is nothing in the context to populate the heading, so it remains empty.

If you are using ClassBased views you can let the views also inherit from one another or have a common ancestor in order to have both context variables present